# Get FirebaseUser object for different users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The Firebase Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) say the following:

> A Firebase User instance is independent from a Firebase Auth instance. This means that you can have several references to different users within the same context and still call any of their methods.

**QUESTION:** How to get/create `FirebaseUser` instances for other users? I got an admin user who can change profile info of other users, like photo url or display name.

Comment: I would recommend saving those users on the Firebase Realtime Database. This way, when you want to get some user data, just query on the database.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, I just wonder what's the point of including those lines in documentation when nobody can use it anyway.

Comment: Maybe they will give us that ability on newer versions of the api